# Blood analysis devices: how and where is the data saved

Tags: database, data-download, data-management, data-preprocessing

I've read that there are blood analysis devices that can automatically determine the data for each specified analyse. You can expect to get the results in less than a day.

Q: How and where do they store the information? Is there a database of the provider or the clinic? Are all the device providers saving the data in the same format?

Comment: They use a separate secured specialist networks because of data protection issues. Encrypted harddrives are used at my place. There is no format requirement, the requirement is data security. For research it is formulated by ethics committee

Comment: @MichaelG. so basically it is a hard drive attached to the device. Nobody using a HIPAA/GDPR compliant service(cloud)?

Comment: We're a bit off topic here, essentially yes. However, it is within a restricted access firewall. It's research however not point of care diagnostics and UK not USA